# Laravel 4.2 - backup automatically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, backup

I have an project laravel 4.2 and i need to make on backup for all the files automatically with code.

Am try to find on package but all the package not supported Laravel 4.2.

So please if someone has a solution tell me cause i need it.

Thanks all

Comment: Can you remote SSH to the server?

Comment: You can use a shell script and Amazon S3 or similar backup service. Your question is quite broad and may or may not have anything to do specifically with Laravel. If you show some effort toward the solution you're likely to get better support here.